# Entity Framework - Parent to Children When Child Has Composite Primary Key - Insert Error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And then the Fluent setting in the data context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.ParentId })
                .HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
                .WithMany(p => p.Children)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I'm doing this so that I actually delete the child object when I say `parent.Children.Remove(aChild);`, not just set its `ParentId` null.

The problem is, I'm getting the error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Child'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Child'. The duplicate key value is (0, 2)." when I create a fresh parent with children, and then `db.SaveChanges()`:

```
Parent p = new Parent { Name = "Quarterbacks" };
            p.Children.Add(new Child { Name = "Brady" });
            p.Children.Add(new Child { Name = "P. Manning" });
            p.Children.Add(new Child { Name = "Kaepernick" });
            p.Children.Add(new Child { Name = "Wilson" });
            p.Children.Add(new Child { Name = "Rodgers" });

            db.Parents.Add(p);

            db.SaveChanges();
```

I thought integer primary keys are auto-generated on insertion. What should I do? Should I change the keys to strings and create GUID keys in C# for this to work?

Comment: did u try adding key attribute on top of child entity id. I know you are already doing it via fluentapi. I would use sql profiler to see what's generate in sql server.

Comment: Set it to Cascade-on-Delete, don't make up a fake key with an optional part.

Comment: Cascade on delete will work but that's when I delete the parent and its children would also be deleted. The thing is, parent.Children.Remove(child) is only removing the relationship, not the child off the database.

Comment: That's because you said `.HasOptional(c => c.Parent)`.

Comment: Changed all keys to string, and manually generated the GUID in C#, and changed .HasOptional to .HasRequired - works as expected. I just don't get why it doesn't work for integers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for *composite* keys no part of the key is marked as an identity *by default*, even not for integer keys (which would be the case for a simple, non-composite key). You probably must add the `Identity` option explicitly to the `Child` entity's `Id` property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .Property(c => c.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

I'm a bit worried that your second part of the `Child`'s key is nullable. Perhaps EF does allow that, but the database not necessarily: I think, with SQL Server for example nullable key parts are forbidden. Maybe, other databases can deal with that. You're apparently aiming for an *identifying relationship* (the one that deletes the child from the database when it is removed from the parent) which however needs a required (not an optional) relationship between parent and child, as far as I know.